# Strange Property Behavior in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I'm working in JavaScript and building up my page with some DOM-elements. I get some strange issues in Firefox using this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function Button()
            {
                var that = document.createElement("div");
                return that;
            }

            function ContextMenu()
            {
                return new Button();
            }

            function onLoadPage()
            {
                var a = new Button();
                var b = new ContextMenu();
                a.contextMenu = b;
                console.log(" ->", b);
                console.log(" -->>", a.contextMenu);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="onLoadPage()"></body>
</html>
```

---

Console logs in Google Chrome:

```
 -> <div></div>
 -->> <div></div>
```

Console logs in Firefox:

```
 -> <div></div>
 -->> null
```

---

If I change "a.contextMenu" to "a.contextMenuu", it works in FF correctly and as expected. It doesn't matter what I assign. It seems that the property name is reserved or something? So why is this like this? And can I do anything to allow me to use ANY property names in my objects?

Comment: `dataset` is a [`DOMStringMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMStringMap) and it actually works. @Taplar I would like to accept your comment ^^

Comment: @Bitterblue - How is `new ContextMenu()` a **DOMStringMap**? (`dataset` is a DOMStringMap: It stores key/value pairs, where both the key and value are *strings*.) In your Chrome console.log output, it looks like `b` is a `div` element, not a string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Misunderstanding. I wasn't talking about my objects, but about the proposed "dataset".

Comment: If dataset doesn't keep your object as an object, it's not really an answer to your specific question, :)  That was my bad.  I was thinking that if dataset was set programatically, rather than from the markup, that it might keep it as an object, rather than as a string.  I was incorrect.

Comment: Ok. You're right. I printed the value without checking its type. It's a string. So I ended up setting up `a.customData = {};` and I put my objects there. GUI works, divs are visible and operable.

Comment: Why do you use `new Button()` instead of `Button()`? The function isn't an object constructor.

Comment: It's better this way, since I use functions like classes/constructors to create my objects.

Answer (score 0):

[`contextMenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contextMenu) is an experimental technology currently supported in Firefox and Edge. So trying to use that property for something *else* won't work, just like trying to use `parentNode` for something else won't work.

> And can I do anything to allow me to use ANY property names in my objects?

Either don't use your own custom properties on DOM elements ("expando" properties), or use a prefix that's unlikely to conflict with current or future web standards, like `myAppContextMenu` or similar.

Depending on what browsers you need to support, you may be able to use [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) (even IE11 supports...most of it) to avoid storing properties on elements. Instead, you'd use them as the key in a `WeakMap`, and use an object as the value, with the properties you want there. The `WeakMap` won't keep the element in memory if it's removed from the DOM.

Comment: Do I have to create `a.WekMap = { };`? I didn't find it anywhere in my DOM objects.

Comment: @Bitterblue - You'd store it separately: `const elementData = new WeakMap();` then `elementData.set(a, {b: b})`. Later if you need `b`: `elementData.get(a).b`. And again, if `a` is removed from the DOM and no other references to it exist, it will get removed from the `WeakMap` automagically.